# Solve: $|z|^2+2zi+2\overline{z}i+3=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$|z|^2+2zi+2\overline{z}i+3=0$$

$$z\overline{z}+3+i(2z+2\overline{z})=0+0i$$

$$1)\text{  }2(z+\overline{z})=0\iff 2Re(z)=0\iff Re(z)=0$$

$$2)\text{  }z\overline{z}+3\text{  }=0$$

due to $Re(z)$ we get:

$$2) \text{  }yi\cdot(-yi)+3\text{  }=0$$

$$2) \text{  }y^2=-3\iff y_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt{3}i$$

So we have $$z_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt{3}$$

but if we plug it back to the equation we get:

$$3\pm 4 \sqrt{3}+3=0$$ Which is obviously incorrect

Comment: $y$ is a real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly found that $\Re(z)=0$. The equation reduces then to $|z|^2+3=0$, which has no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(z)=0$, then also $\overline{f(z)}=0$, so you have
\begin{gather}
|z|^2+2zi+2\bar{z}i+3=0\\
|z|^2-2\bar{z}i-2zi+3=0
\end{gather}
and summing them up you get
$$
2(|z|^2+3)=0
$$